# Android / OneSignal - Know if the clicked notification was grouped

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, onesignal

So the question is quite self-explanatory. I want to know if the notification clicked was grouped or was a single notification. Based on which, an Activity will be launched.

For example, if the notification was grouped, I would like to launch the "All messages" Activity, and if not, it'll simply launch the Chat Activity.

This is what my current code looks like:

```
public class NotificationOpenedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler {

    private Application application;
    String message;

    public NotificationOpenedHandler(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    @Override
    public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {

        // Get custom data from notification
        JSONObject data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;


        message = data.optString("message");
        startApp(message);
    }

    private void startApp(String text) {

        Intent intent;

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = application.getSharedPreferences("appdata", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (sharedPreferences.getInt("pending_notifications", 1) > 1) {
            intent = new Intent(application, DemoActivity.class);
        } else {
            intent = new Intent(application, ReadLetterActivity.class);
        }
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("pending_notifications", 0);
        editor.apply();
        intent.putExtra("message", text);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

As you can see, I tried playing with SharedPreferences, but it was not up to the mark.

Wrapping up, I wanna know if there's a way (native or provided by OneSignal) to know if the notification was grouped or not. Thanks.

Comment: from my knowledge when the notification is grouped... if i tap it, the notification opens up to view the notifications in the group. i know onesignal has a android_group option, and im pretty sure they offer a way to know how many notifications are there for the users... you can use that int for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. Found the way out. This works flawlessly to distinguish between single and grouped notifications, even if a notification from a group is opened separately.

```
@Override
    public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {

        if (result.notification.groupedNotifications == null) {

            // if the clicked notification was single/clicked separately from a group
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Single notification", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {

            // if the clicked notification was grouped
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Grouped notification quantity: " + String.valueOf(result.notification.groupedNotifications.size()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}
```